# Blackberry Http Push Application connection refused

Tags: java, blackberry, connection, push

I'm trying to develop an http push application on Blackberry. 
I'm using the sample application from the blackberry documentation (HttpPushDemo).

When I test to run it server side on localhost and send a message, the console tells that the connection is refused. Here is the error message:

```
Sending to http://localhost:8080/push?DESTINATION=2100000A&PORT=100&REQUESTURI=localhost
Waiting for notification on port 7778...
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

The client application (in blackberry simulator) is already listening.

fyi, this is the doc that I follow : http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/7649/Setting_up_for_JDE_organizer_1009971_11.jsp

Comment: On localhost, so you are trying to test it on simulator?

Comment: I also get the same problem, @MisterSmith yes, i tried it on localhost and it's on the simulator :D

Comment: Did you configure the MDS config file? (`rimpublic.property`) Did you launch it before launching simulator?